# Twitch thumbnail not visible in webview

Tags: react-native, iframe, twitch, react-native-webview, react-native-render-html

I am working on a React Native app that displays HTML content using the [react-native-render-html](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/) library. This HTML data is coming from content formatted in WordPress. The same content is also being displayed in the web app made with ReactJS. I am also using [this iframe plugin](https://github.com/native-html/plugins/tree/master/packages/iframe-plugin), as recommended by the `render-html` library, to display the `iframes` in my HTML.

I have the following problem with rendering Twitch video embeds.

The Twitch embeds are in this format:

```
<iframe src="https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=ShortHelpfulSquirrelCmonBruh-hWj49qxBfx-VKseO&amp;autoplay=false&amp;parent=my.parent.domain" width="640px" height="360px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Please note that these are not live streams, but clips. The ReactJS website displays these embeds correctly with the thumbnail:

[image: Twitch embed on Web]

With the same embed code, however, my React Native app displays the embed without the thumbnail but with just a black background (although it shows the title and controls):

[image: Twitch embed on mobile before playing]

Once I play and pause the video, the background does not remain black, however:

[image: Twitch embed on mobile after pausing]

Here is the `rendererProp` that I am passing to the library for `iframes`:

```
iframe: {
  scalesPageToFit: true,
  webViewProps: {
    scrollEnabled: false,
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: true,
    javaScriptEnabled: true,
    domStorageEnabled: true,
    userAgent: Platform.select({
      ios: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.15",
      android: "Chrome/56.0.0.0 Mobile android",
    }),
  },
}
```

I am passing the `IframeRenderer` and `iframeModel` as imported directly from `@native-html/iframe-plugin` (linked at the beginning) into the `renderers` and `customHTMLElementModels` props of the `<RenderHtml/>` component. Also I am using the `WebView` from [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) lib.

My team and I cannot figure out why the thumbnail is not appearing in the `react-native-webview`, but works fine in the website. If anyone has any experience rendering Twitch video iframe embeds on `react-native-webview`, please take a look. Any help will be appreciated.